# EF recovery from invalidoperationexception caused by server being down

Tags: entity-framework

I had a windows service relying on EF, and it was running fine until the server went down.  The problem was after the server went up again, it didn't fix itself and still threw the error:

> INTERNAL ERROR: Execution of the command requires an open and available connection. The connection's current state is broken.

Not being very proficient in EF I'm not aware of how I could recover from such a scenario, and why it occurred in the first place? Anyone had this happen before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is the lifetime of your ObjectContext?  If you are using a single ObjectContext for the lifetime of your service that would cause problems like this.  You should instead scope the ObjectContext lifetime down to a smaller window of time, creating a new one for each unit of work.

Comment: Ohhh.. So I can't reuse them. -_-

Comment: sorry, how should i do like this ? i mean down to a smaller window of time ?

Comment: Suggest you post a question with your code if you want specific advise on how to reduce the length of time you are holding on to an object context.  In the limit you would create an object context, make one change to the database and then close it - that would be the smallest window of time possible.

Answer (score -1):

Solution described [here](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH159177) worked for me,
modify the connection timeout in your connection string

> FROM server='MySQLServer'';Integrated Security=true;Initial
>   Catalog='EVConfiguration';Connection Timeout=100  TO
>   server='MySQLServer';Integrated Security=true;Initial
>   Catalog='EVConfiguration';Connection Timeout=0

Comment: If anything you should increase the timeout to something that encompasses your longest request.  If you specify an infinite timeout, you'll have the potential of a lot of un-closed connections.

Comment: I think you're confusing connection timeout with command timeout. you can't set the command timeout on a connection string