# Execution of the command requires an open and available connection. The connection's current state is broken

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis-7

Serious problem with entity framework & sql server 2008, please help!!
System works well locally but during load test at production server we have following error for more then 10 users.

After get this error user can not logged in anymore.

Server Error in '/' Application.
Execution of the command requires an open and available connection. The connection's current state is broken.

Here is SQL Server Log

```
3005
An unhandled exception has occurred.

9/13/2011 3:41:14 AM

9/13/2011 7:41:14 AM

73b3f335f4de45fa8c4ef2f22809300b

4911

482

0

/LM/W3SVC/14/ROOT-3-129603711416579333

Full

/

E:\WebSites\Medtrack2.0\

COLO-VDEV01
15864

w3wp.exe

NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

InvalidOperationException

Execution of the command requires an open and available connection. The connection's current state is broken. at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source) at Dashboard.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

http://38.127.112.89:9010/Dashboard.aspx

/Dashboard.aspx

119.148.4.83

JMiranda

True

Forms

NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

11

NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

False

at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection() at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source) at Dashboard.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

have any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF recovery from invalidoperationexception caused by server being down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863224/ef-recovery-from-invalidoperationexception-caused-by-server-being-down)

Answer (score 4):

See if the answer to this similar question can help you:

[EF recovery from invalidoperationexception caused by server being down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863224/ef-recovery-from-invalidoperationexception-caused-by-server-being-down)

or this one:

[Exception: Execution of the command requires an open and available connection. The connection's current state is broken.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/c5533b3d-19d0-4e78-9a3b-a6920eed65d1/)

Answer (score 0):

How are you storing the ObjectContext?  From an EF perspective, you have to make sure each user gets a unique reference to the ObjectContext.  To do that, I share the ObjectContext by storing it in the HttpContext.Current.Items collection.  See this for more information on the Items collection: http://abhijitjana.net/2011/01/14/when-we-can-use-httpcontext-current-items-to-stores-data-in-asp-net/