# .NET Core process crashing due to an SQL connection pool exception

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, azure-sql-database

I recently migrated a .NET Framework 4.6.1 application to .NET Core 2.1 and the process is crashing when the SQL AZure database becames unavailable. The process runs on Windows as a Service.

The problem itself is not the exception (it is an [expected condition of SQL Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193503/azure-sqlexception-database-on-server-is-not-currently-available)) but the fact that I'm unable to handle the exception since it is not occurring in my code directly. It seems the exception is occurring in the SQL connection pool.

I collected the stack trace below by listening the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Database 'XXXXXX' on server 'XXXXXX' is not currently available.  Please retry the connection later.  If the problem persists, contact customer support, and provide them the session tracing ID of 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX'.
>      at new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, object providerInfo, bool redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, bool applyTransientFaultHandling)
>      at DbConnectionInternal System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at DbConnectionInternal System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at DbConnectionInternal System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>      at void System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.PoolCreateRequest(object state)
>      at bool System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
>   ClientConnectionId:3873debc-b302-44f5-820a-8f760b1634e3
>   Error Number:40613,State:1,Class:14

This is not a new code and the behavior seems different when running on .NET Framework, where the process didn't stop.

Comment: There is a retry feature in the connection string which you could leverage or use a lib like polly.net.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that there is a bug in the package `System.Data.SqlClient` for versions until `4.5.0`

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14615#issuecomment-389248862

Comment: And what version were you using?

Comment: I was using the 4.3.1

Answer (score 1):

If your client program connects to SQL Database by using the .NET Framework class `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`, use .NET 4.6.1 or later (or .NET Core) so that you can use its **connection retry** feature. For more information on the feature, see this webpage.

When you build the connection string for your SqlConnection object, coordinate the values among the following parameters:

> ConnectRetryCount:  Default is 1. Range is 0 through 255.
>
> ConnectRetryInterval:  Default is 1 second. Range is 1 through 60.
>
> Connection Timeout:  Default is 15 seconds. Range is 0 through 2147483647.

Specifically, your chosen values should make the following equality true:

Connection Timeout = ConnectRetryCount * ConnectionRetryInterval

For example, if the count equals 3 and the interval equals 10 seconds, a timeout of only 29 seconds doesn't give the system enough time for its third and final retry to connect: 29 < 3 * 10.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connectivity-issues#net-sqlconnection-parameters-for-connection-retry

Or install Polly.Net:

> Install-Package Polly

More about that found on their GitHub: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly