# Azure Web app cannot connect to the database hosted at the same resource group

Tags: database, azure, blazor

I created a Blazor web app hosted in Azure. I added a SQL Server and database to the same resources group.

I connect to the SQL Server using Dapper, and it works from Visual Studio to the local database.

I set the Azure DB Connection string, and it works, I can see the content of the DB at Azure from my local execution.

I commit the app to Azure, wait for it to be deployed, visit the URL and the changes are there, but the app is unable to connect to the database.

I get the following error message:

> Database 'r---' on server 'r---server.database.windows.net' is not currently available.
> Please retry the connection later. If the problem persists, contact customer support, and provide them the session tracing ID of '{E952B***-54EA-4A1A-99A6-1F96****6A2F}'.

In the DB configuration page in the Azure portal, I have:

- Public network access: Selected Networks
- Virtual Networks: none
- Firewall rules:

  - Client IP : 212.***.***.*** (my local dev IP)
- Exceptions

  - Allow Azure services and resources to access this server (ON)

I'm a bit lost with all those settings, so please expect any goofy unexpected wrong setting here and there.

Comment: similar issue here :https://stackoverflow.com/q/23193503  and I'm afraid a restart might be useful..... because I even failed to sign in Azure just now for testing , and I used another browser which helped me finally.

Comment: But as I said it works flawlessly running from my IP. It systematically fails to run from the Azure web app. Does not seem to be a transient thing.  Rebooting the app instance also did not help :(

Answer (score 0):

@Tiny wang Thanks for your comment.

Ensure that your network connection is stable and that you can reach the server, as network issues can lead to connection problems.

Make sure your firewall settings allow connections to the specified server and database.

Verify the connection string used in the application, ensuring it contains the correct server name, database name, and password.

I Used the code from this [document](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implementing-dapper-in-blazor-server-application/).

The ConnectionString appears as follows below.

**appsettings.json** :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DevDB": "Server=tcp:<serverName>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<DatabaseName>;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=UserName;Password=<Password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
}
```

**SalesServices.cs**:

```cs
using BlazorApp14.Data;
using Dapper;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlazorApp14
{
    public class SalesServices : ISalesService
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly string _connectionString;
        public SalesServices(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DevDB");
        }
        private SqlConnection CreateConnection()
        {
            var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Open();
            return connection;
        }
        public async Task<bool> DeleteSales(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
                parameters.Add("SalesId", id, DbType.Int32);
                using (var conn = CreateConnection())
                {
                    await conn.ExecuteAsync("DeleteSales", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        public async Task<IEnumerable<SalesDto>> GetSales()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var conn = CreateConnection())
                {
                    return await conn.QueryAsync<SalesDto>("GetSalesDetails", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        public async Task<SalesDto> GetSalesById(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
                parameters.Add("SalesId", id, DbType.Int32);

                using (var conn = CreateConnection())
                {
                    return await conn.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<SalesDto>("GetSalesById", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        public async Task<bool> SaveSalesDetails(SalesDto sales)
        {
            try
            {
                var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
                parameters.Add("ProductName", sales.ProductName, DbType.String);
                parameters.Add("Quantity", sales.Quantity, DbType.Int32);
                using (var conn = CreateConnection())
                {
                    if (sales.IsUpdate)
                    {
                        parameters.Add("SalesId", sales.SalesId, DbType.Int32);
                        await conn.ExecuteAsync("UpdateSales", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await conn.ExecuteAsync("SaveSalesDetails", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.razor** :

```html
@page "/"
<h2>Sales Entries</h2>
<hr />
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ProductName" class="control-label">Product Name</label>
                <input for="ProductName" class="form-control" @bind="@sales.ProductName" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Quantity" class="control-label">Quantity</label>
                <input for="Quantity" class="form-control" @bind="@sales.Quantity" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @if (sales.IsUpdate)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@UpdateSales" value="Update" />

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@CreateSales" value="Save" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    @if (salesEntries == null)
    {
        <h3>Please wait, Loading the data.</h3>
    }
    else
    {
        <table class='table'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Options</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var sales in salesEntries)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@sales.ProductName</td>
                        <td>@sales.Quantity</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" value="Edit" @onclick="() => GetSalesById(sales.SalesId)" class="btn btn-primary" />
                            <input type="button" value="Delete" @onclick="() => DeleteSales(sales.SalesId)" class="btn btn-danger" />

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
</form>
```

**Index.razor.cs** :

```cs
using BlazorApp14.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace BlazorApp14.Pages
{
    public partial class Index
    {
        IEnumerable<SalesDto> salesEntries;
        [Inject]
        public ISalesService SalesServices
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        SalesDto sales = new SalesDto();
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            await this.GetSalesDetails();
        }
        protected async Task GetSalesDetails()
        {
            salesEntries = await SalesServices.GetSales();
        }
        protected async Task CreateSales()
        {
            await SalesServices.SaveSalesDetails(sales);
            await this.GetSalesDetails();
            this.ClearAll();
        }
        protected async Task UpdateSales()
        {
            await SalesServices.SaveSalesDetails(sales);
            await this.GetSalesDetails();
            this.ClearAll();
        }
        protected async Task GetSalesById(int SalesId)
        {
            sales = await SalesServices.GetSalesById(SalesId);
            sales.IsUpdate = true;
            await this.GetSalesDetails();
        }
        protected async Task DeleteSales(int SalesId)
        {
            await SalesServices.DeleteSales(SalesId);
            await this.GetSalesDetails();
        }
        public void ClearAll()
        {
            sales.ProductName = string.Empty;
            sales.Quantity = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I added the current IP address to the Azure SQL Server as shown below.

[image]

This is my **Local Output** :

[image]

I successfully published the Blazor server app to the Azure App Service using Visual Studio.

[image]

**Azure App Service Output**:

[image]

Comment: I can flawlessly access the database if I access it from my developing computer. As you wrote in the answer, I added my IP to the firewall in Azure and declared the BD as publicly available. There is no problem there.  The problem arises when I try to access the DB from the app deployed in Azure itself. In the same resources group where the DB is.